# How to monitor RAM usage for Hyper-V VMs?

Tags: monitoring, hyper-v, memory, usage

A bit of context first : on Windows 2008 Standard x64 with 8Gb RAM, I have 5 VMs running which should take up 1664Mb RAM (3*256Mb+384Mb+512Mb). There is nothing else running on this server except the basic OS components (this not a Core installation). I know that each VM will use more RAM on the host than what has been configured in Hyper-V.

But when I run the task manager, it says 6.7Gb used ! If I sum up the RAM used by each process in the task manager (showing all users processes), I get to something around 1Gb...

So : how can I check how much RAM each VM is really using on the host (it does not seem to be available via task manager) ?

Note that I am aware of the fact that my problem could be unrelated to VM RAM usage, but I would still very much like to know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the trial versions of either SCVMM or Hyper9 to manage your Hyper-V environment, at least temporarily.  It sounds like you need to invest in a management tool for your virtual infrastructure.

Comment: As a matter of fact, our virtual environment is not critical (yet) : we use it to test our developments/deployments. And we also use it to gain experience in virtualization matters. The tools you mention seem quite an (expensive) overkill for the first purpose, but trying them would definitely fit the second one.

Answer (score 1):

I think with Performance Counters you can see that.

Look at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tvoellm/monitoring-hyper-v-performance
which has a section

> A common question I get is – “how much memory is a VM using?”

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a Hyper-V machine handy to make sure it works, but take a look at Sysinternal's VMMap (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx)

From the description:

> VMMap is a process virtual and
>   physical memory analysis utility. It
>   shows a breakdown of a process's
>   committed virtual memory types as well
>   as the amount of physical memory
>   (working set) assigned by the
>   operating system to those types.
>   Besides graphical representations of
>   memory usage, VMMap also shows summary
>   information and a detailed process
>   memory map. Powerful filtering and
>   refresh capabilities allow you to
>   identify the sources of process memory
>   usage and the memory cost of
>   application features.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I think you may have mistaken VM (Virtual Machine) for VM (Virtual Memory). Anyway, it made me think of trying the very handy Process Explorer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx